# Which kind of hosting to pick for network?

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I have created a network that is based on php (mysql)... It runs perfectly on offline servers (with xampp). It is supposed to be a website (mainly for users with PCs) so I used HTML, CSS, jQuery/JavaScript and php. Now I am done and do not know which kind of hosting to pick. Of course I will need to work with some program like filezilla as far as I know and do I need dedicated servers for that or can I simply use normal webhosting, too? Or is even neither of those wrong? Please help me, I'm totally lost... :/

Comment: As you like, I pushed it into an answer :-) Good luck and... have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any cheap or free web hosting provider will be able to provide your requirements. The only downsides would be 1. performance, 2. you typically get only one single mysql database and 3. flexibility.

The single mysql database allows you to use as many tables as you want (maybe limited by storage size, though). So using table name prefixes you might be able to operate multiple applications.

If you think about doing other things too in future (backups, own email service, other servers, ...), then you want to take a look at a service offering virtual servers. They come for a few Euros a month these days, the exact price obviously depends on the power and storage volume you require.